# Where do I report Stellar-related scams?

Tags: key

Found a post on a forum saying they are stellar.org. Then they ask for your secret key. Where should I report this scam and others like it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to Stellar only. There are multiple scam sites for other cryptocurrencies. I don't think there's a good way to fight it other than educating users to not post their secret keys anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is a valid concern (and I am actually part of the SDF Team so your concern has been heard), this is not the best place to post this message. In the future the Stellar Public Slack is the best place to voice these concerns -- in fact there is a #scam channel there.

Comment: Posting to the Stellar sub reddit is a good option as well.