# I GOT SCAMMED, Any Recovery?

Tags: xlm

Any chance of recovering my lumens? I have the destination address and was able to get additional details thru StellarExpert.

Note: It was the email phishing scam, "Stellar Community Staking Marathon"

Comment: Let me know if you find out. I filed a police report and Internet Fraud Complaint with the FBI https://www.ic3.gov/default.aspx this morning. I lost 200,000.00 XLM due to this same phishing scam last night. Luckily it wasn't more.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly simply no.  Related: https://stellar.stackexchange.com/q/697/683